# Zsh filling associative array with read from file leads to strange separation

Tags: zsh, associative-array, associative

I have a textfile generated by
`find Path -printf '%s\t%p\n' > textfile`
When I do

```
 declare -A DICT;
 while IFS='\t' read -r SIZE PFAD
 do DICT[$SIZE]=$PFAD
 done < ../Listen/textfile
```

the content of DICT surprises me:

print "${(@k)DICT}"
shows, that the keys of DICT are not just the SIZE of the files, but consist of
SIZE\tRoot_of_PFAD/2_letters_of_following_directory.
The values contain the rest of the line = Rest of the path with the filename.
Looks to me as if read separates the lines by '\t+9 characters'

Comment: `IFS='\t'` sets the internal field separators to `\ ` and `t`, not to `tab`. Try `IFS=$'\t'`, or remove the assignment (tab is in the default IFS set).

Comment: @Gairfowl Didn't change a thing.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
IFS=$(printf '\t')
```

seems to have done the trick.
@Gairfowl hinted in the right direction.
I hadn't grasped, that the tenth character in the path was a t.
Thank you very much!